# How do you add a new argument to a pure function without having to update all calls to the function?

Tags: functional-programming, refactoring, purely-functional

I make a pure function (example in js, but the question doesn't depend on the language) with one input argument and call it all over my application.

```
var day = 'Tuesday';
var doYouExist = function(you) {
    return !!you;
}
```

Then I realise that I should only check if you exist on Tuesdays so I decide to update the function...

```
var day = 'Tuesday';
var doYouExist = function(you) {
    if (day === 'Tuesday') {
      return !!you;
    }
}
```

But now it's not pure. I could add day as an argument, but the day variable isn't available in all of the places doYouExist() is called.

So my choices are either:

1. Use an impure function
2. Inject 'day' to all of the places the function is called, then update the function and every call to that function to include a second argument.

Until now I've been using choice 1, but I don't know the recommended pattern (or any way to actually achieve what I want) for a functional approach.

Comment: Very interesting question. (I am quite new to functional programming so be skeptic about my comment). I guess that you can't. Perhaps you have found a good example of why imperative programming beats functional programming in some ways. I guess that choosing between option 1and option 2 has to do with how one values on the one hand the ability to change a function in one place, and on the other hand the security and explicitness of functional programming. I am looking forward to read the answers to this question.

Comment: This makes me think of the _reducers_ in _Redux_. A reducer in Redux takes an (extra) argument called _state_ which essentially contains all application state in a big javascript object (POJO). So one (stupid?) way might be to usually send in a state argument to functions that _may_ be dependent upon the global state and then have stuff like the current day in the state.

Comment: Is `var day` a mutable variable or a constant?

Comment: if `day` is a constant, your function is still pure. You could always make `day` a function parameter, too.

Comment: @Bergi day would be mutable (if I wasn't worrying about trying to purify functions that is) I was thinking something along the lines of checking the local time and updating the day in real time.

Comment: @naomik Even if it was a constant, the function wouldn't be pure since the function output would no longer depend on the inputs alone. Constants may still change during development or between different application instances.

Comment: I'm curious: if it is as you say that "the day variable isn't available in all of the places doYouExist() is called," then how is `doYouExist` available in those places. That doesn't really make sense to me. In other words, it would help me answer if you could give an example of the two kinds of places where you'd call this function?

Comment: @P0lska you misunderstand the concept

Comment: @naomik You're right. I read on wikipedia "The function result value cannot depend on any hidden information or state that may change while program execution proceeds or between different executions of the program". So for that statement to be true, changing a constant such as the day of the week and running two instances should be considered as two distinct applications, not two instances of the same application.

Comment: @P0lska you cannot "change" a constant – if you edit a constant's value in your program and re-run it, you ran two completely different programs. If `day` is not a constant, then your function is impure. See [Why is Today() an example of an impure function?](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/184574/why-is-today-an-example-of-an-impure-function)

Answer (score 0):

If `day` is a constant, then you don't need to do anything, because your function is still pure.